# Rails ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

Trying to load my app, but it's bombing out with the following error.

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (
(in /Users/mattmessinger/Work/fanbread/repos/toaster/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap-bower/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js)):
  4:     %title FanBread
  5:     = stylesheet_link_tag    'onboard/onboard', media: 'all'
  6:     %link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans")
  7:     = javascript_include_tag 'onboard'
  8:     = favicon_link_tag 'shared/favicon.ico'
  9:     = csrf_meta_tags
 10: 
app/views/layouts/sessions.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_sessions_html_haml___3847274540096119980_70339212302360'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `sign_in'
lib/fan_bread/custom_domain_cookie.rb:14:in `call'
lib/fan_bread/canonical_host.rb:13:in `call'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You'll need to provide more information on what you've done to debug the problem.  Without that info, your question won't be a great fit for theQ&A style here, since too many 'commentary question's would need to be asked to help you!

Comment: What is the actual path to the onboard.js file? It appears to bomb on line 7.

Comment: `onboard.js` is located in `app/assets/javascripts/onboard.js`. I've also added this file to `assets.rb` so it gets picked up by the asset pipeline.